# Convert varchar to numeric in vertica

Tags: database, vertica

Is It possible to change `varchar(10)` column to data type `numeric(10,4)` using alter statement.

I tried it with alter command but getting an arror:

`cannot convert column from varchar(10) to numeric(10,4)`

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert directly from VARCHAR to a numeric type, but you can work around the restriction by creating a temporary (numeric) column, populating it based on the current column, and then renaming it.  When populating it, you'll need to make sure that the value is actually a number, for example that it does not contain commas as separators, punctuation like $, etc.

The [documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Tables/ColumnManagement/WorkWithColumnDataConversions.htm) gives this example, where the original price column has values like '$50.00':

```
ALTER TABLE sales ADD COLUMN temp_price NUMERIC(10,2) DEFAULT 
  SUBSTR(sales.price, 2)::NUMERIC;

ALTER TABLE sales ALTER COLUMN temp_price DROP DEFAULT;

SELECT MAKE_AHM_NOW();

ALTER TABLE sales DROP COLUMN price CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE sales RENAME COLUMN temp_price to price;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help..I have gone through it.

Comment: What I had is '$'  sign in varchar column data and needed to convert to numeric.. I just removed '$' from column data and then used cast as numeric

Comment: @MonicaCellio, i know its an old question, but instead of `SUBSTR` its better to use in function `to_number`(x7 faster). For example: `select to_number('$50.0', '$9999.9999');` Also this implementation more portable and supported by other dbms'es.